# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()

Tags: java, android, firebase

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I have a launcher activity `UserEmailAuth` that has a button to handle user login by Firebase's `GoogleSignIn`. When I try to make the `UserEmailAuth` the `LAUNCHER` Activity, the app does not launch from any of the methods: USB Installation, Emulator, or Generated APK.

But, interestingly, when I bypass the user login and make my `MainActivity` as the launcher activity and then press the `LogOut` from the `MainActivity`, it is redirected back to the `UserEmailAuth` from there it works fine.

Following is the trace, which is not an error and is generated regardless of the Bypass Method or the Original Method.

```
W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6371)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:930)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:820)
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@267c3e2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.bytebeetech.wildtripurafoundation-2/lib/arm64
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/AccessibilityManager: current package=com.bytebeetech.wildtripurafoundation, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
I/art:     at void com.bytebeetech.wildtripurafoundation.user.activities.UserEmailAuthentication.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (UserEmailAuthentication.java:60)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6854)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2709)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
```

Below is the class which implements the logic of GoogleSignInOptions

**UserEmailAuthentication.java**

```
public class UserEmailAuthentication extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 101;

    public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPreferences";
    public static final String IS_ADMIN = "is_admin";

    public String is_admin;

    Button signUpButton;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    UserUtility userUtility = new UserUtility(UserEmailAuthentication.this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_email_authentication);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        init();
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.myProgressButton);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (userUtility.checkInternetConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    ProgressUtility progressUtility = new ProgressUtility(getApplicationContext(), v);
                    progressUtility.buttonActivated();
                    signIn();
                } else {
                    userUtility.showSnackbar("You are not connected to the INTERNET", v, getApplicationContext());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        checkUserProfile(firebaseAuth);
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Log.d("Inside", "signIn: ");
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                Log.d("Inside", "onActivityResult: ");
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "SignIn Failed, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(UserEmailAuthentication.this, UserEmailAuthentication.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        // SHOW PROGRESS BAR
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            checkUserProfile(firebaseAuth);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("---------------", "------------------------");
                            Log.d("Error ","Message: "+task.getException());
                            Log.d("---------------", "------------------------");
                        }
                    }
                    // HIDE PROGRESS BAR
                });
    }

    private void checkUserProfile(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        final FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentFirebaseUser != null) {
            String user_id = currentFirebaseUser.getEmail();
            db.collection("users").document(user_id).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                String is_admin = documentSnapshot.getString("is_admin");
                                saveSharedData(is_admin);
                                if(is_admin.equals("true")) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserEmailAuthentication.this, AdminActivity.class);
                                    View view  = findViewById(R.id.myProgressButton);
                                    ProgressUtility progressUtility = new ProgressUtility(getApplicationContext(), view);
                                    progressUtility.buttonFinished();
                                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    }, 3000);

                                } else if(is_admin.equals("false")) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserEmailAuthentication.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            } else {
                                //String is_admin = documentSnapshot.getString("is_admin");
                                //saveSharedData(is_admin);
                                String user_email = currentFirebaseUser.getEmail();
                                String user_photo_url = currentFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(UserEmailAuthentication.this, UserDataAuthentication.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                Toast.makeText(UserEmailAuthentication.this, "Passing Email: " + user_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(UserEmailAuthentication.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please SignIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void saveSharedData(String is_admin) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(IS_ADMIN, is_admin);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

**Using these for my project to support Firebase Functionalities**

```
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
   
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
```

**ProgressUtility.java**

```
public class ProgressUtility {

    private MaterialCardView materialCardView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    private TextView textView;

    Animation fadeIn;

    public ProgressUtility(Context context, View view) {
        materialCardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewProgressBtn);
        constraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutProgressBtn);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.msgText);
    }

    public void buttonActivated() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView.setText("Please Wait...");
    }

    public void buttonFinished() {
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(materialCardView.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView.setText("Done");
    }
}
```

**progress_btn_layout.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewProgressBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutProgressBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGoogle">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/yellow"
                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/msgText"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.917"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/msgText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Continue with Google"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**user_email_auth.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutEmailAuth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activityBackground"
    android:padding="24dp"
    tools:context=".user.activities.UserEmailAuthentication">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/myProgressButton"
        layout="@layout/progress_btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*This is the class where the layout is initiated which has one Google Sign in button. Even if I remove the sign option and implement a simple Toast, the errors are the same.*

I have also Invalidate the Cache and Restarted and Cleaned and rebuilt as I have no idea where it is coming from.

I even do not know whether it is due to a Firebase Version Conflict or on my MIUI Problem (Xiaomi Version COnflict). Even on the Emulator, it has the same errors.

Any suggestions would help

Comment: Post the code that causes the error. Put yourself in our shoes: could you diagnose an issue with nothing more than a partial stack trace? Also, take a look at the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue) for MessageQueue. Do you see an `enableMonitor()` method there?

Comment: Yes, as described in the contents fof the question it has a message which says `W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch`

Comment: @MarsAtomic What else should be edited? I have tried to add all the necessary details. Please let me know

Comment: @MarsAtomic: Please cross-check the question. .. I have updated

Comment: Good edit. Welcome back.